# Url redirect in codeigniter Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I make an app in which Admin will be able to create service, add some content and save. On save CMS panel will display a URLs to Admin.
Everything works fine.Requirement is to give URLS like that

```
www.abc.com/servicename/contents.php
```

When user access this URL, how can I manage that it will come in my home controller and contents action.

How can I implement that?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Do you mean when user access www.abc.com/servicename/contents.php he/she should be redirected back to the home(default) controller ?

Comment: Have a look I have posted a detailed answer.

Comment: Have you made authentication and checking current user level already?

Comment: Yes it will also made

Comment: Already have been made or need to be made?

Comment: You have to make that first. Using sessions you can limit users of visiting specific pages. There are nice packages for CI auth already. Try with [Ion auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is codeigniter is pretty straight forward.

[redirect()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

`redirect()` Does a "header redirect" to the URI specified. If you specify the full site URL that link will be build, but for local links simply providing the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to will create the link.

> **Note:** In order for this function to work it must be used before
>   anything is outputted to the browser since it utilizes server headers.

This function resides in url helper, if you are not autoloading url hepler then you should manually load it prior to calling redirect() `$this->load->helper('url');` After that you can call `redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');` to redirect to your desired controller.